# Sql inner join with three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this problem, I am a newbie in SQL. I have 3 tables:

`TBL_PRODUCT`:

```
    prod_id, 
    prod_type, 
    prod_code, 
    prod_desc
```

`TBL_DOCUMENT`:

```
    doc_id, 
    doc_name, 
    doc_expiry, 
    doc_term, 
    enable_amt
```

`TBL_DOCUMENT_GROUP`:

```
    grp_id, 
    prod_type, 
    doc_type, doc_id
```

For every document, there are corresponding products, one to many. What I can't figure out is how can I display the products of each document. Thank you in advance!

I'm so sorry but I really don't know how to do it, all I know are the basics of SQL.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the schema you are providing, I will assume that you find all the products of each document based on 
1. which document_group the document is in 
2. which product_type the document_group is associated with
If that is the case, this is what your query would look like:

```
SELECT doc_id, prod_id
FROM tbl_document AS td
JOIN tbl_document_group AS tdg ON td.doc_id = tdg.doc_id
JOIN tbl_product AS tp ON tdg.prod_type = tp.prod_type
WHERE doc_id = 1;
```

However, the scheme you outlined above is a little unconventional.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that ties the prod_id from TBL_PRODUCT to any document in TBL_DOCUMENT.
The only matching thing you can come up with is : 
   Given a document (from TBL_DOCUMENT) and joining it with TBL_DOCUMENT_GROUP you can tell what product group it falls into.
   But you can never match up one document to one product (that's what is missing in this design).

This is the closest you can get:

```
  select a.doc_id, a.doc_name, c.prod_type --// but not prod_id...that will create a cross join 
  from TBL_DOCUMENT a
    inner join TBL_DOCUMENT_GROUP b
      on a.doc_id = b.doc_id
    inner join TBL_PRODUCT c
      on c.prod_type = b.prod_type
```

i.e. Either the TBL_DOCUMENT table is missing a prod_id or you need another table that defines the relation between a doc_id and a prod_id...

Comment: @Olivier De Meulder....I understand your logic but "he" really doesn't understand what he wants..i guess you know this solution is not good and he will realize it pretty soon :-)

Comment: yeah ... I agree with you :-)